# Angularjs, ng-model, ng-repeat and input calculation

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and in most situations I don't have a problem figuring out how to do something. However I have a controller that calculates payments based on different criterias, you can see the basic idea [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3JlG0lMKwWJL3DpUJtE6?p=preview). It's really simple you enter an amount and you enter number of payments and you get a table with input results, so they can be edit if needed. What I'm trying to do is when one of the amounts is changed, I whish the rest of them to be re-calculated. For example, if I have amount of 200 and total of 2 payments (100 each) if I wish the first payment to be 50 instead of 100, the difference to be added to the 2nd payment or distributed through the rest of the payments if they are more. I can't find a way to identify the payments after ng-repeat has created them in order to updated the rest of them. 
I don't want anyone to do the work for me, just if someone can point me in to the right direction.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) on paymentResults and update the payments with the new values.

```
$scope.$watch('paymentResults', function (newVal,oldVal) {
    //calculate updated payments
}, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works to a certain point. I can get the difference, but how do I only update the input fields that are not manually changed ?

Comment: @species I guess there is no easy way. You have to compare the updated array with the old one to see which of them are not changed.